# resolve.conf can't be changed - docker-alpine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

**What am I trying to achieve:**

I'm starting 2 containers on 2 different instances in AWS.
I also have a route53 local domain to hold the records of these instances.
When I ping from 'web' instance to 'db' instance I use "ping db.domain.local" and cannot use only "ping db" (and vice versa).

**What I did so far:**

Changed the file /etc/resolv.conf from

```
search domain.local
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

to (changed the "options")

```
search domain.local
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:1
```

**What I got:**

Got it to work.

**Error I got:**

When I try to change the /etc/resolv.conf file in the Dockerfile or the docker-compose process I get the error

> can't move '/etc/resolv.confOobcMn' to '/etc/resolv.conf': Resource busy.

**Workaround for now:**

Don't have one because I'm trying to get it to work with the Dockerfile build or the docker-compose up process

**My infrastructure is:**

```
Containers OS: Alpine Linux 3.4 based
Docker: 18.09.2
Docker-Compose: 1.23.2
Host OS: ubuntu \ MacOS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently changing the `docker` command in the `systemd` unit file works.

All you have to do is to add `--dns-opt=ndots:15` to the `ExecStart` line inside `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` (depending on your distro) as one of the arguments to the command line and restart docker.

As suggested at the [following issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32093) on github.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overwrite the resolv.conf in a docker container. Docker does some interesting things with resolv.conf to get a lot of their internal networking (GWBridge, Overlays) working.

You may want to try using their --dns-opt=OPTIONS flag when starting the container, or updating your docker-compose to handle the dns flags:

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/

Comment: I would like to use "--dns-search" but it's not available in the docker-compose format.. So it's unfortunately it's not a solution :-\